# Reading and analyzing .cdf file using python

Tags: python

I am trying to read a .cdf file and I have to analyze the data using python. I am using Spyder 5.1.5 to rum my code. This is the first time I am working with .cdf and I have no idea how it looks or what it is. After spending a lot of time I somehow figured out how to read a .cdf file. I used the Spacepy library. Below is the code I used.

```
from spacepy import pycdf
cdf = pycdf.CDF(r'C:\Users\chadd\Downloads\to\cdf.cdf')#cdf is name of my file
print(cdf)
```

When I run the code I get something like this: [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UNrRC.png)

I checked about this error on the internet and from what I understood it says that I do not have all the libraries, but I can see spacepy installed in Environment in Anaconda Prompt.

I am so confused. Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`spacepy` is a wrapper around the CDF library, but it does not include the library.  The doc pages gives you the link from which to load that library;

https://spacepy.github.io/pycdf.html

https://cdf.gsfc.nasa.gov/

Comment: How can I download it from https://cdf.gsfc.nasa.gov/? It takes me to a bunch of directories which in turn open more directories. Which one should I download and how?

Comment: There's a link to "Download the released version", then "download the official version", then "Windows", then you probably want a 64-bit VS2015 version.  Use one of the installers for the easiest path.